# Regex to define if statements

Tags: java, regex

my target was to write my own programming language and I think that the regex will be better for this purpose. My problem is to define if statements it doesn't work:`(\s|^)if\s*\((.*?)\)\s*then\s+do\s+(.*?)\s+end\n+((elif\s*\((.*?)\)\s*then\s+do\s+(.*?)\s+end\n+|else\s+then\s+do\s+(.*?)\s+end\n+)*)`

And my language : 
`if (condition1) then do 
 aagahd;
end
elif (condition2) then do
 dhriebf
end
elif (condition3) then do 
 fhdiebjdhd
end
else then do
vahfhf
end`

So I want to search "zero or more elif  OR   zero or one else"
And also if I have more than one elif the regex takes condition only from last elif. What I did wrong? (I'm working on Java)

Comment: Have you researched programming languages at all? There is a fairly common way of doing it that works pretty well. Perhaps regex are a brilliant solution and no one has thought of it before. Perhaps people do it a different way because it is much clearer easier to modify and maintain etc...

Comment: [This](https://www.ioccc.org/1991/dds.c) isn't actually regex (appearances to the contrary).

Comment: @John3136 I'm with you, but there is no need for sarcasm. Can you provide a link to some resource? I bet this would help OP.

Comment: @Zabuza OP can google "Write programming language" just as easily as I can. I just did it. The first link that came up for me mentions lexing and parsing

Comment: Regexes aren't the way to do this. You should give [ANTLR4](http://www.antlr.org) a try.

Comment: I agree with what everyone is saying. I don't want to sound all high-and-mighty, but regex just gets really messy and slow. You need a grammar parser, like YACC, bison, or ANTLR. That's how most programming languages are written.